# Eclipse Error-The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library

Tags: eclipse

I Downloaded Eclipse from-https://eclipse.org/downloads/
From where i got -eclipse-inst-win64.exe
After intalling it,when i launch it, It is throwing me an error
The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.
I am having Windows 8.1-64 bits, Java SE Runtime Environment-Build 1.8.0_77-b03

Answer (score 0):

very simple and easy solution for this problem. This problem occurs only because of versioning of eclipse . so need to clear the versions of jars which are in the eclipse.ini . Easy way to fix this is just remove eclipse.ini and run your eclipse application file it will automatically creates new eclipse.ini as per your environment